# Player health will not go down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have tried to make it so whenever the enemy collides with Player1 health drops, i have all of the public floats and transforms setup, but the health in the debug menu shows it just doesnt go down, any ideas?

(attached to player1)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
private float health = 0f;
public  Transform player; 
[SerializeField] private float maxHealth = 100f;

private void Start() {
    health = maxHealth;

}
public void UpdateHealth (float mod) {
    health += mod;

    if (health > maxHealth){
        health = maxHealth;
    } else if (health <= 0f){
        health = 0f;
        Debug.Log("Player Respawn");

    }

}
```

}

attached to enemy:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyAttack : MonoBehaviour
{ 
[SerializeField] private float attackDamage = 10f;
[SerializeField] private float attackSpeed = 1f;
public Transform player;
private float canAttack;
// Start is called before the first frame update
private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D other) {
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player1"){
        if (attackSpeed <= canAttack){
            other.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerHealth>().UpdateHealth(-attackDamage);
            canAttack = 0f;
        }else {
             canAttack += Time.deltaTime;
        }

}
```

}}

Comment: Is the detection code successfully detecting a collision? Add some more debug lines in there to check that the code is actually running.

Comment: And here I will show my unity ignorance. What is the purpose of the SerializableField attribute on the maxhealth? Should you have one on the health as well?

Comment: Is it player1 or Player1?

Answer (score 0):

You are serializing the *Max Health*, not the current health, so the value shown in the inspector will never change. Add the SerializeField to the health value as well and you'll see the current health.

```
[SerializeField]
private float health = 0f;
```

Beyond that, it's difficult to see if the code isn't working. I would ensure that the tag you're checking for is actually set on the Player, and add a debug message to `OnCollisionStay2D` to ensure the collision handler is being called. If it isn't, ensure you have the collider components on both the enemy game object and the player gameobject.

Depending on your intention, you may want to move the `canAttack` modifier to `Update()`, since your current logic will only "refresh" the `canAttack` timer when the enemy is actually colliding with the player. If the enemy hits a player and the player runs away, and comes back ten minutes later and runs into the enemy, the enemy won't attack, they'll only start "healing" their `canAttack` timer until it's ready again. Maybe this is what you want, but I suspect that it should go into `Update()` so enemies that have already attacked "rest up" at all times.